# Backspace deletes prompt in terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

In the following scenario, my bash prompt looks like this:

```
Username@Hostname ~ $
```

If I type any number of characters, and then press the delete button one-too-many times, it will clear the entire line. For example:

```
Username@Hostname ~ $ ls
```

then I delete `s`

```
Username@Hostname ~ $ l
```

then I delete `l`

```
|
```

I'm then left with my cursor without any sort of prompt. I can type up commands normally and everything seems to function fine--but why does the prompt disappear? Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using escape sequences to color (or otherwise add content) to your prompt without marking the escapes as "non-printing", bash will lose track of the column, and result in behavior like this.

bash's [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-prompting) suggests that you put nonprinting characters in your prompt within `\[` and `\]` markers.

For the given example

```
PS1='\[\033[1;32m\u@\h\[\033[00m \[\033[1;34m\w $\[\033[00m '
```

a possible improved version would be

```
PS1='\[\033[1;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[1;34m\]\w $\[\033[00m\] '
```

Comment: `PS1='\[\033[1;32m\u@\h\[\033[00m \[\033[1;34m\w $\[\033[00m '` Did I not use the escape characters correctly?

Comment: The answer to my question, is no. Needed to put a `\]` at the end of each escape sequence. Thank you!